# Loading external html pages from a database in ionic1

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am current making a dynamic mobile application that loads some custom assets such as html and css from a database but am failing to get it to work. I have tried the sce in angularjs 1 but it still has issues with it. The first issue is it's not trusted if I use trustAsHtml and the second is a digest keeps running for long loading hundreds of errors if I use trustAsResourceUrl. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish my task will be appreciated.

My approach is as follows:
1. View

```
  <div ng-include src="{{getHtml(vm.user.html.path)}}"></div>
```

2. Controller

```
function getHtml(url) {
  if (url) {
    var newPath = url.substr(1);
    var asset = 'https://www.slywolf.org' + newPath;
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(asset);
  }
}
```

Comment: did you use `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala, I have added the process i used above.

Comment: did you can use the `domSanitizer` for pass the URL as a trusted URL?  also  use the `<iframe>` tag to  pass the URL

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala, Sorry for the late reply. I tried out what you suggested without luck. Iframes do not work with the html files am using as i have angular tags in side style blocks to style pages based on a page index.